# Oracle Case Statement when x is null then else returns null

Tags: sql, oracle, case, case-statement

I have written a simple case statement as below:

```
case when col_name is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end as col_name
```

But I'm still getting (null) instead of a 'NO' ? Any ideas?

I have tried following still no luck:

```
case when isnull(col_name, 0) = 0 then 'NO' else 'YES' end as col_name
```

I have also tried this:

```
case when nvl(col_name, 0) = 0 then 'NO' else 'YES' end end as col_name
```

I know that NULL is never equal to NULL - NULL is the absence of a value. NULL is also never not equal to NULL.

---

Whole query looks something like this:

```
Select 

t1.col_a,
t1.col_b,
t1.col_c,
.
.
t2.col_a
t2.col_b

from table_1 t1
 left join table_2 t2 
  on t1.col_a = t2.col_a

 left join
 (select distinct

  case when t3.col_name is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end as col_name,
  t3.col_a,
  t3.col_b,
  t3.col_c) ABC

on abc.col_a = t2.col_a
```

Comment: This `case` *expression* cannot return `NULL`.  You have something else going on, such as an outer join or subquery.

Comment: Maybe you are getting blanks that look like null, e.g. ' '. In that case: `case when trim(col_name) ...`.

Comment: what do you get when you try `nvl2(col_name,'YES','NO')` ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan same result.

Comment: can you share the complete query you are trying

Comment: @GordonLinoff there is a join here. So I have a main query and doing a left join select statement and my case statement is within it. Do you think there is an issue there? Case statement is to determine if something exists in left join select ... I might switch to exists query instead.

Comment: then you should have some hidden chars such as null as Thorsten mentioned, perhaps carriage returns. try with `dump(col_name)` also

Comment: Your main select list doesn't include `abc.col_name` so where are you seeing that it is null? You haven't shown it including any columns from the `abc` inline view so do you think that outer join is actually finding anything (i.e. `abc.col_a = t2.col_a` is ever true), and if so why? The case expression might just belong in the outer select list, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Will you post the entire query?  What you are presenting does not have T3 defined so you should be getting "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected".  Also, a representative sample of data for T3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` is returning `NULL`, not the `CASE`.  Return the column name and do the `case` logic in the outermost query:

```
select . . . ,
       (case when t2.column_name is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end)
```